# Martingale Property {Proof

Tags: black-scholes, martingale

[image][image]

Can someone assist with this proof? I apologize for such a vague post. I have no idea where to begin. I am in a class a little above my level with this stuff. I have added a picture of the proof he is referring to so you can see notation. Thank you!!

Comment: Not clear for your question. You at least need to explain the notations.

Comment: you added the proof which is a good first step, but we will re-open this question once you ask a specific question. As it stands you did not ask anything yet.